# How to send UDP messages to each machine in LAN

Tags: c++, udp

I want to send Udp message to each machine in LAN by not using broadcast. so, my code like this:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

sockaddr_in tarAddr;
memset(&tarAddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
tarAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
tarAddr.sin_port = htons(1985);

char szTarAddr[16] = {0};

for(int i=2; i<255; i++)
{
    sprintf(szTarAddr, "192.168.1.%d", i);

    //if address is me, Ignore by continue...
       ...

    tarAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(szTarAddr);
    sendto(sock, msg, 18, 0, (sockaddr*)&tarAddr, sizeof(sockaddr));
}
```

Only about first 20 machines (192.168.1.2 ~ 192.168.1.20) could receive the message, most of other machines could not receive it.

I try to send to 20 machines, then sleep(5), then send to the other 20 machines, and so on. but this way is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, UDP is stateless, and does not guarantee delivery. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

> There is no guarantee of delivery, ordering, or duplicate protection.

So, you've observed that some of your UDP packets weren't delivered. That's perfectly fine, since UDP packet delivery is not guaranteed.

Comment: My project is an application about mobile and I want to know the mobile's address,   In WIFI of LAN, mobile's address is usually begin by 192.168.1.100, But I can not guarantee it. if I use "for (int i=100, i<120, i++)",  the 192.168.1.2~99 and 192.168.1.121~254  could not receive massages.

Comment: You'll have to figure out some other way to accomplish your goals. Nothing in your comment contradicts, or supplements, the answer.